# What are the differences between 'bear the blame' and 'take responsibility'?

Tags: phrase-usage

> The driver must *bear a large portion of the blame* for the accident.
>
> The driver must *take a large portion of responsibility* for the accident.

Which sentence is correct and what are the differences in meaning?

Comment: Both sentences are correct, but they have different connotations.  In one we are blaming someone, a generally negative act, and in the other someone is taking responsibility, a generally positive act.  So while they are interchangeable to some degree, they do not mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JasonPatterson However in this case "must take a large portion of responsibility for the accident" would mean that it was mostly the driver's fault that the accident happened, so it is not necessarily a positive act.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct (though I will raise a technical issue in a moment) but I think you can examine certain differences by yourself. Clearly, *[blame](http://thefreedictionary.com/blame)* has obvious negative connotations, whereas responsibility is largely of a neutral nature. In this specific case, "blame" directly assumes the driver being at fault, whilst "responsibility" is less stern.

Let's imagine the driver's poorly-maintained vehicle sprays oil all over the road, causing the car(s) behind to crash. We would likely speak of "blame". However, a driver that doesn't ease his speed sufficiently after a "sharp turn" road sign and subsequently smashes off the road needs to take "responsibility" for the occurrence.

**EDIT**
*Take this last point with a pinch of salt*

I don't wish to be pedantic, but an "[accident](http://thefreedictionary.com/accident)" is a bit misused. An "accident" to my mind implies "An unforeseen event that is not the result of intention or has no apparent cause". It's not necessarily misused here but *[incident](http://thefreedictionary.com/incident)* would be a better choice.

**EDIT** *Using (or not) the word "accident" is just something to consider, and not wrong or incorrect in the sentences provided.*

Comment: In line with the subject of connotations, it's worth remembering that, during the Watergate crisis President Nixon made a speech on television in which he accepted responsibility for the actions of his subordinates, and commentators were quick to point out that he had not admitted being to blame.

Comment: I agree with most of this, except for the part about _accident_ being a "bit misused" – _accident_ is the word we use when referring to vehicle fender-benders, despite any assigned cause or fault. See [Definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/accident): _a crash involving road or other vehicles, typically one that causes serious damage or injury_. (I don't mean to be pedantic, either, but I wouldn't want learners to read your answer and think that, after a collision in the parking lot, they'd be better of calling it an _incident_, not an _accident_.)

Comment: You're absolutely right. However, I've been seeing a bit of a trend of avoiding the word "accident" and instead using "incident" in more formal/"official" circumstances. For example, I know the police (and occasionally the written press) use "collision" or "incident" over "accident", simply because "accident" can imply that nobody is to blame. Edited nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

"Bear the blame" is passive. It's acknowledging fault, but not necessarily doing anything about it. "Taking responsibility" is active -- it's about doing what you can to make things right (and might or might not involve also acknowledging fault)